# tableView reloadSections and reloadData white space and cells move to wrong section

Tags: ios, uitableview, sections

The issue is:  When I execute reloadSections, the last cell of one section will jump to the first cell of the next section, even though cellForRowAtPathIndex definetly does not load this cell there (thouogh I did check and it is dequeing that cell, then updating it), and there will be an empty white space (sometimes) where a cell should be in the previous section.  If I run reloadData, my whole table goes white until I scroll aroud a bit at which point it sometimes works.  Background information:

I have a table view, which is displaying data with several rows per section.  In the backgroud, a download may finish, which may or may not update the number of rows in each section and the data contained in the rows. The rows are varying heights, which is expensive for a "reloadData" call, so I don't want to execute that everytime new data arrives (only one section may be updated).

So, what I do when I start displaying a cell is check if a download for that section has been completed, and if it has I then reload that section.  If that section is updated, I check the other sections as well (Since it often downloads sections together), and update all those.

Okay, here is the issue.  I run something like this (abbreviated for simplicity / at work don't have exact code with me):

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
for (int i = 0; i < numSections; i++)
{    
    if ([self sectionNeedsUpdate:i])
    {
        [self updateNumberOfRowsInSection:i]; //if Needed
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSArray arrayWithObject:i] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNon];
    }
}
[tableView endUpdates];
```

The idea is that I update each section individually, but all 5 may be updated in that loop.  Or maybe just section 1 / 3, etc.  Why would a cell just jump to the next section?  Are those reloadSections calls running in their own thread and dequeing each other at the same time?

Comment: Update.  I have found that the duplicated cells are created because cellForRowAtIndexPath passes a separate index path than the actual cell it's updating.  why?

Comment: Well I learned, do not update a section while running cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Causes all kinds of issues. Find a different time to check for updates.